# Filter to only show data after a date which is input in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, date, filtering

I have a data set and I want to only show data after a specified date.
That date will be defined by the end user. I am able to do this for numbers but as soon as I try to do this for date the macro runs and the result is no data shown.

My data sheet is called "Data"
The column with the dates in is the 8th column (field 8)
And the input date that I want to define the data I get is in cell H1
I am in the UK (maybe that has an affect???)
I don't want to start converting my underlying raw data.

I think I am desperately trying to get cell H1 to be "seen" as a date

Code below:

```
Sub Macro_show_data_after_inputted_date

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("C15").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$AJ$2875").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & Range("H1"), _
        Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to duplicate the number formatting in column H into H1 and use `Criteria1:=">" & Range("H1").Text`

Comment: It is interesting that my data is in dd-mmm-yyyy format e.g.. 14-Dec-2015. Which I assumed (never assume) was a date format, albeit a custom date format. However, it doesn't act like a regular date format for these purposes. But your .text input fixes this. For others reading this my final code could be tidied a little also. see below: Sheets("Data").Select
      ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$AJ$2875").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & Range("H1").Text, _
        Operator:=xlAnd

Answer (score 0):

This is a number formatting issue. The [Range.AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) expects its criteria in identical formatting as that of the values it is filtering. The cell's displayed value (aka *formatted text*) can be retrieved with the [Range .Text property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840217.aspx).

```
Sub Macro_show_data_after_inputted_date

    with Sheets("Data")
        if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode = false
        with .Range("C15")
            .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">" & .Range("H1").TEXT
        end with
    end with

End Sub
```

If you record the same operation and intentionally mistype the date format, you will see in the resulting recorded code that it is correctly before use as a string criteria.